# Blazor Server - How to handle situation when user is faster then SignalR?

Tags: signalr, blazor-server-side

I have a complex Blazor server app and I run into situations that user interact with the form and while the server is trying to manipulate the DOM via SignalR, the user manage to do other things in the form.
When I debug the app or using PC in the LAN, it works fine because it is very fast.
But when I browse from cell phone it is noticeable.

One of those situations is reading a barcode using barcode reader.
The flow is:

- user scan barcode into textbox
- the barcode is validated
- if OK or Bad the user gets a message
- the textbox cleared

What happen is that the user is able to scan other barcode before any render is being done to its DOM.

It seems to me that it has to be done with some JS locally.

Any solutions ideas would be appreciated

Tx
Yaron